# how to scan javascript code to find errors (are there any programs do that)?

Tags: javascript

how to scan javascript code to find errors (are there any programs do that) ?

Comment: Try [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)

Comment: JSLint will hurt your feelings :)

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo: Whereas some browsers will hurt your feelings by passively-aggresively gobbling up error messages and then being deliberately unhelpful. "Object expected on line 0", know what I mean? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load it into Firefox, and use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/) plugin. It enables you to debug JavaScript, and to see where errors are located in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a number of programs have plugins etc that can be used to detect common errors and syntax problems.

If I were you I would start here,
[JS Lint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/download.htm) or [here](http://www.jslint.com/)

In addition, each most browsers have a Javascript console where you can see errors reported and debug your code. Safari and Chrome have it in-built, for Firefox download [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/), and of course [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)